# Windows 8 Metro Apps - Windows App Certification Kit Failing

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I've made a metro app using C# and XAML. It is (as far as I know) ready to upload to the store. Obviously, though, I wanted to test it with Windows App Certification Kit. When I tested it, though, it failed. There were several categories it failed in, but the failures were always related to two reasons:
1) Failed to launch App
and 
2) Failed to extract imported API information for this application.

For the first reason, I looked at help. It says to open the app in the start menu and check that it runs, which is fine. The second, I couldn't make heads or tails of.

I'm running all of this on a school laptop, which has fairly intrusive protection and user account controls. Could this be my trouble? If not, then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failed to extract imported API information for this application is probably cause by an external dependency. You should check all the library that you are using and check that they are compatible with winRT. For "Failed to launch App " if it happen only when you are doing the WACK test you can look in the event log if you can get more information about why it fail to launch (click right on the bottom left corner of the screen and  click Event Viewer)

Comment: I'm fairly new to windows 8 apps, so I apologize for my ignorance, but what libraries would be incompatible. I'm not really using anything special; it's all in either the Windows or System namespaces. I think that the only using statement I added was `using Windows.Storage`.
Also, I checked event viewer and it said that "app is not registered for Windows.Launch contract or not installed".

Comment: I was talking about external libraries (That you would have added with nugets or just manually added using Add Reference). But I'm guessing from the error about "app not registered or not installed", the app may failed to installed because you don't have admin access on the computer.

Comment: One other thing you could try is uninstalling is just installing a package of the app and try to launch it (Project->Store->Create Package). After that go in the package directory, click right on Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 > Run in Power Shell, make sure you answer the question to allow it to install. Look for error during the instalation and once it's install try to run it and see if that work.

Comment: I uploaded it to the Windows store and it passed fine, so I guess it was just that I didn't have the right admin privileges.